# Windows Batch Auto Watch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, timer

I have one batch file for "watching" others, by simply skipping to the next if the current batch is taking too long.

Here is the watch file itself currently:
First, I take the current time and convert it to a whole number.
Just so you know, %1 is the file name of the batch itself to run and watch.  %2 is the amount of time in minutes to watch for until skipping if it doesn't complete on it's own.

```
set "ptime=%time: =0%"
set "stime=%ptime:9=8%"
set /a "ttime=(%stime:~0,2% * 60) + %stime:~3,2%"
```

Then I run the batch file (I use my "auto watcher" to call and insert values into the file to use, this part has no issues but I include it for full reference here)

```
call "%1.bat" %3 %4
```

Then I set this variable I set when calling the watcher file, which is the time in minutes to wait until skipping to the next batch:

```
set two=%2
```

Finally, I run another set of variables

```
:auto_watcher
%slp% 5
set "atime=%time: =0%"
set "btime=%atime:9=8%"
set /a "rtime=((%btime:~0,2% * 60) + %btime:~3,2%) - %ttime%"
if %rtime% GEQ %two% echo Taking too long!  Skipping..&exit
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MAGICUSB\%1" /v EndTime >nul 2>nul || goto auto_watcher
exit
```

(for my purposes I have a reg entry named "MAGICUSB" to store the information)
The last part checks if the batch file currently running has ended by itself, so as to end the watcher, otherwise if it takes too long it just exits and the parent batch file continues to the next.

..however my code does not work.  It should, it used to, but something must have changed and I must have forgot before.  Try it yourself, making a file called auto_watcher.bat, placing all of this code into.  Then create a file or so, and use the parent batch file to call the watcher file, and place the file name after and an amount of time.

Comment: You may want to consider using the [WAITFOR](https://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html) command instead.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `set "stime=%ptime:9=8%"`?

Comment: Atleast with how I convert the time to a number, it rounds the time down, whereas normally if I don't change 9 to 8, for some odd reason it seems to bug out the time-keeping.  I'm converting the time to a single number.  It works but not sure why exactly.